# Ionic don't compile last changes

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm getting a problem compiling my App using Ionic 2 framework.

I just noticed there was a bug and trying to fix it, I just changed the app login url from the client's server to my test server, also added a few console.log. The problem is that after changing the code and compiling the code, the cordova still compiling the app without the console.log and to the client server.

I have tried

> npm uninstall -g ionic
>
> npm install -g ionic
>
> cordova platform rm android --save
>
> cordova platform add android --save

I also have cleaned my mobile cache and data and did a reset on it too.

Thank you in advance for the help.

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I was using PowerShell to launch the commands, changing it to the normal CMD running as administrator, it compiled the latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in case somebody else has same problem
in package.json I update "@ionic/app-scripts" from 0.0.43 to 0.0.44 and then npm install
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.44",

try this
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/363

Comment: That didn't work for me... I solved it by using the command line instead of PowerShell